# Why does my python post request does not work?

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
url = 'https://supremenewyork.com/shop/304070/add'
headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*;q=0.5, text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript',
    'Origin': 'https://www.supremenewyork.com',
    'X-CSRF-Token': 'cGh34LIXA5O75UEl+ArjyIQA/CS6BGY9mFleXXZ5GnznS4t8y2rGTpUTumG93EHNwSfnkDDtsYLvbEGbmMymRQ==',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
}
post_data = {
    'commit': 'add to basket',
    'size': '53133',
    'style': '25229',
    'utf8': '✓'
}
session.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=post_data, timeout=1)
r = session.get('https://supremenewyork.com/shop/cart.json', headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

Post data is correct, i took it from Google Chrome, but every time code return nothing (because basket is empty). How do i do post request correct?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @mad_
I do not have any error, just this code does not add item to cart

Comment: Have personally not used `request.session` but the article here is apt for your question. I think use session with `with` statement should resolve the issue https://medium.com/@anthonypjshaw/python-requests-deep-dive-a0a5c5c1e093